# PHP email style

Tags: php, html, css, email, styles

So on a website I am working on there is an automated email sent when you register.  When it sends it shows the css.

```
$body '<span style="color:#444444;">Header</span>';
```

I also tried this code that I found online that had style=\"asdas\" then used a command to remove the slashes but that didn't work either.  Is there a simple php code that will just simply embed the html in the email?

Comment: You need to put an `=` between $body and your string. It's unclear what you're asking; what isn't working with your current code, and what _specific_ problem are you having?

Comment: And realize that whether or not a user sees HTML email is entirely up to the user, not you.

Comment: Did you indicate that it's an html email in the header?

Comment: And to second @JamWaffles, make sure you are using the right syntax and also have a look at the PHP IDE's available(if you're not using one already) as well as PHP debugging techniques and methods. This will save you a lot of time and make your code quality at least a little bit better.

Comment: If you are sending HTML directly, consider using one of the PHP mailing libraries - there's all sorts of intricacies to sending multipart email, and they're best done using a well-tested codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you put the `$body =` as @JamWaffles suggests.

Next, are you setting your headers correctly?

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a pretty detailed tutorial here: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

It shows importance of headers, HTML vs txt email and user desires. It should be a good starting point for you.

You can also add a tld check in your code and assume they would have an html capable email client/web interface(gmail/yahoo/live etc) or you can just ask them to provide you with this information and then send them the emails in the format they have asked you to.